# Web Safe colour matching service (Like Adobe Kuler but...not)

Tags: css, user-interface, colors

As more of a developer, colour theory comes a little bit more difficult to me. Are there any CSS colour services which would allow me to input a hex colour value and it give me complimentary colours to go onto a webpage. I know of Adobe's Kuler, but frankly the interface was awful and i couldnt really find what i was looking for!

I'm talking background colours, typography, shadows. All the UI features which can be made to look awful with the wrong colours.

Comment: belongs on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://colorschemedesigner.com/